# edge deletions and spanning subgraphs

Tags: graph-theory

The following is from [Graphs and Digraphs 6th Edition by Chartrand, Lesniak and Zhang](https://www.crcpress.com/Graphs--Digraphs/Chartrand-Lesniak-Zhang/p/book/9781498735766):

> For a vertex $v$ and an edge $e$ in a nonempty graph $G = (V, E)$, the
>   subgraph $G-v$, obtained by deleting $v$ from $G$, is the induced
>   subgraph $G[V-\{v\}]$ of $G$ and the subgraph $G-e$, obtained by
>   deleting $e$ from G, is the **spanning** subgraph of $G$ with edge set
>   $E-\{e\}$. More generally, for a propert subset $U$ of $V$, the graph
>   $G-U$ is the induced subgraph $G[V-U]$ of $G$. For a subset $X$ of
>   $E$, the graph $G-X$ is the **spanning** subgraph of $G$ with edge set
>   $E-X$.

( The bold applied to the two instances of the word "spanning" is due to me.)

Earlier on the terms *subgraph*, *spanning subgraph*, *edge-induced subgraph*, etc. were defined. In particular:

(In my own words) **$H$ is a spanning subgraph of $G$** if they have the same vertex set and the edge set of $H$ is a subset of the edge set of $G$. And (quoting the text again):

> For a nonempty set $X$ of edges of a graph $G$, the subgraph $G[X]$
>   **induced by** $X$ has $X$ as its edge set and a vertex $v$ belongs to
>   $G[X]$ if $v$ is incident with at least one edge in $X$.

It appears to me that the last clause of the previous definition leaves open the possibility that the graph $G - X$ in the first block of quoted text need not be a **spanning** subgraph of $G$ because if $X$ contains edges incident to leaf vertices, then these vertices won't be in $G-X$.

Am I correct that the authors made a mistake or am I getting lost in the sea of definitions?

Comment: I don't follow.  One paragraph is talking about spanning subgraphs, and one is talking about edge-induced subgraphs.  What is it that you think  mistaken?

Comment: @saulspatz that the subgraph induced by removing one or more edges from $G$ is necessarily a spanning subgraph of $G$, which the text appears to me to be implying.

Comment: I don't see where it says anything about a subgraph "induced by removing edges".

Comment: you're right, I was reading more into the definition of $G-X$ than was there!

Comment: Glad you got it straightened out.  I didn't figure out what was confusing you until I was going to sleep last night.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you may be conflating the last two statements made in the first quote.

The second statement: "For a subset  of , the graph − is the spanning subgraph of  with edge set −." holds true.

By the spanning subgraph definition you gave, G-X must be a spanning subgraph. The vertex set, V(G), is unaltered if you remove a subset of edges, and therefore V(G)=V(G-X). Furthermore, E-X is a subset of the edge set E of G. (Thus fulfilling both conditions of a spanning subgraph)

Note: G-X does not need to be an induced subgraph. The final statement of the paragraph you quoted is self-contained. The induced subgraph part of the paragraph only applies to when you're deleting vertices as the book stated.